# Hibernate Formula annotation, SQL query with parameters

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to change one property of entity to be calculated as SQL aggregate function, where the query must join certain tables on the value which is known at runtime.

The example query is following

```
select count(1) cnt
from foo foo
left join bar bar on (bar.foo_id = foo.id)
where
   foo.type= 'X' and bar.username= 'Y' and
   foo.creation_date >= sysdate -  ( Z / (24*60) );
```

Where `X` is retrieved from an association of the particular entity, `Y` is the authenticated user in the Spring `SecurityContext`, and `Z` is property defined in the maven profile.

Is it possible to use Hibernate's `@Formula` annotation with runtime built query?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this purpose?